# 'Modes' in Control Theory

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, linear-control

What is the meaning of 'Mode' in control theory , in many places while studying linear system theory and  control specially controllablity,observability,stabilizability and detectability i saw people using the word 'modes' instead of poles or eigen values.

Are they the same ? if so then why do we use 'mode' ? what is the reason behind using this specific word ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvalues and poles only tells you at what "frequency" it moves, with frequency I am referring to the complex value $\lambda$ such that its time evolution can be characterized with $e^{\lambda\,t}$. A mode considers this as well but also the mode's shape. For a state space model the shape of a mode refers to the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

In finite element analysis modes are used as well, called modal analysis in which the eigenvectors also have a physical meaning. Namely these vectors show the normalized displacement of the approximated system when only that mode/eigenvalue is excited. But for state space models in general you can apply any similarity transformation and still obtain the same outputs. Under these transformations the eigenvalues remain unchanged, but the eigenvectors can change, so the shape of a mode does not have to be meaningful.

Comment: then it's like the Eigen structure of the system ?

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light I am not familiar with the term eigenstructure, but after a [quick search](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section5/pmc532.htm) it seem to be equivalent to the eigen decomposition. However, that source does state that the system matrix would be diagonalizable, which is not the case for Jordan blocks bigger then size one. But an eigenmode does not only refer to the set of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but also how they can be used to describe the time evolution of the system.

Comment: See the respective section in Chapter 6.2 of Astrom & Murray's "Feedback Systems" book (free pdf available online) for more details on this explanation.